# Meaning of a henry ford quote

Tags: meaning

What are some possible meanings for the Henry Ford quote,

> How come when I ask for a pair of hands, I get a human being as well?

Comment: Have you given any thought to what it might mean? Let's hear what you think.

Answer (score 4):

The internet believes the quote is

> Why is it every time I ask for a pair of hands, they come with a brain attached?

and regardless of who said it, it means that he wanted a tool, but the tool asks questions and complains instead of just doing what it is told.

Comment: Hmm, I can find this quote on various quote sites, but there's no context. Was Ford complaining that he wants mindless automata, or was he saying that this is a good thing? Without the context it's hard to say. Anybody have a source with the broader context?

Comment: Ah, those were the good old days of capitalism, when industrialist plutocrats could openly complain about how "lazy" and "whiny" the working classes are without it affecting sales or the stock price.

Comment: @Jay - assuming he did say that, I am pretty sure he meant exactly: "Do the job, do not ask why or complain about anything"

Comment: @mplungjan The wording just struck me as odd. If that was the intent, it seems funny to use the word "brain", which implies reason and thought. If I wanted to say that, I would have used "loud mouth" or "big mouth", which would be understood to imply argument. In other contexts Ford praised creativity and inventiveness. On the other hand I understand that he ran the company pretty autocratically.From a one sentence quote, one can only speculate. That's the problem I often have with quotes with no context.

Comment: The quote relates to whether or not the tool can think for itself and hence give the employer trouble - it is a very capitalistic quote - I cannot verify the source